# How can I share a gif image using UIActivityViewController with Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, image, gif, uiactivityviewcontroller

I have an app that lets the user record a short video and generate a gif image. Now I want to give the user the possibility to share that gif image using UIActivityViewController, I've done this:

```
UIImage *img = ...

NSArray *objectsToShare = @[img];

UIActivityViewController *avc = [[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:objectsToShare applicationActivities:nil];

NSArray *excludeActivities = @[UIActivityTypePrint];

avc.excludedActivityTypes = excludeActivities;

[self presentViewController:avc animated:YES completion:nil];
```

The problem is that this only shares an static .jpg image (like the first frame of the original .gif image).

On the other hand, the user can save the gif image to the camera roll, and from there it is possible to share it as a .gif. So how can I do the same thing but from my own app?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I managed to do this, and now I can share gif images by email, but I thing there is something left to do with Twitter.

```
UIImage *img = ...;

NSError *err;
NSData *imgData = [imageSerialization animatedGIFDataWithImage:img error:&err];
NSLog(@"%@", err);

NSArray *objectsToShare = @[imgData];

UIActivityViewController *avc = [[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:objectsToShare applicationActivities:nil];

NSArray *excludeActivities = @[UIActivityTypePrint, UIActivityTypeAssignToContact];

avc.excludedActivityTypes = excludeActivities;

[self presentViewController:avc animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Comment: Try wrapping the NSData in a custom implementation of `UIActivityItemProvider` and implement `dataTypeIdentifierForActivityType` to return `kUTTypeGIF`

Answer (score 0):

Share GIF File For WhatsApp:

```
    NSURL *imageUrl =[self.ImageArray objectAtIndex:currentPhotoIndex];
    NSString *path=imageUrl.absoluteString;
    NSArray *strings = [path componentsSeparatedByString:@"/"];
    NSString *mygif=[strings objectAtIndex:strings.count-1];

    NSString *documentsPath = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *dataPath = [documentsPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"/MrHRamani"];

    NSString *filePath = [dataPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:mygif];

    NSURL *urll=[NSURL fileURLWithPath:filePath];
    NSLog(@"imag %@",imageUrl);
    self.documentationInteractionController.delegate = self;
    self.documentationInteractionController.UTI = @"net.whatsapp.image";
    self.documentationInteractionController = [self setupControllerWithURL:urll usingDelegate:self];
    [self.documentationInteractionController presentOpenInMenuFromRect:CGRectZero inView:self.view animated:YES];
```